# Possible generalization of conjectures involving sets and sumsets of positive integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Thinking on diverse conjectures and theorems, and trying to generalize them all, I have come to the following:

> **Conjecture** Let $S$ be an infinite set of positive integers $S=\{a_{0},a_{1}, a_{2},...\}$ such that:
>
> - The sequence of integers is strictly increasing: $a_{k+1}>a_{k}$
> - Either $1$, or both $2$ and $3$ belong to $S$.
> - It exists $N$ such that $a_{k}< 2a_{k-1}$ for all $k\geq N$
> - For every subset $\{a_i,a_{i+1},...,a_{i+N}\}$ it holds that $\gcd(a_i,a_{i+1},...,a_{i+N})=1$
>
> Then, every positive integer $x\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ greater than or
> equal to $a_{N}$ belongs to $S$ or is expressible as a sum of at most
> $a_{0}+N$ equal or distinct elements of $S$.

Some examples supporting the conjecture:

- The series of the triangular numbers $T=\left\{ 1,3,6,10,15,...\right\}$ verifies that (i) the sequence is strictly increasing, (ii) $a_0=1$, (iii) $a_{k}<2a_{k-1}$ for all $k\geq2$, and (iv) $\gcd(a_i, a_{i+1}, a_{i+2})=1$ for every subset $\{a_i,a_{i+1},a_{i+2}\}$. Therefore, according to the conjecture, every positive integer $x\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ greater than or equal to $6$ belongs to $T$ or is expressible as a sum of at most $3$ equal or distinct elements of $T$. This statement was already proved by Gauss ("Eureka" Theorem).
- The series of the prime numbers $P=\left\{ 2,3,5,7,11,13,...\right\}$ verifies that (i) the sequence is strictly increasing, (ii) Both $2$ and $3$ belong to $P$, (iii) $a_{k}\leq 2a_{k-1}$ for all $k\geq1$ and (iv) $\gcd(a_i, a_{i+1})=1$ for every subset $\{a_i,a_{i+1}\}$. Therefore, according to the conjecture, every positive integer $x\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ greater than or equal to $3$ belongs to $P$ or is expressible as a sum of at most $3$ equal or distinct elements of $P$. This statement is equivalent to the strong Goldbach conjecture.
- The series of the Fibonacci numbers $F=\left\{ 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,...\right\}$ (i) is not strictly increasing, and (iii) it does not exist $N$ such that $a_{k}< 2a_{k-1}$ for all $k\geq N$, so it cannot be claimed that every positive integer $x\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ greater than or equal to $2$ belongs to $F$ or is expressible as a sum of at most $N$ elements equal to or distinct from $F$. In fact, it can be shown that $N$ is strictly increasing for the values $x=\{12,46,46,135,...\}$, which are given by $a_{6}+4$, $a_{9}+12$, $a_{11}+46$, $a_{13}+135$,....
- The series of the square numbers $C^{2}=\{ 1,4,9,16,25,36,...\}$ verifies that (i) the sequence is strictly increasing, (ii) $a_0=1$, (iii) $a_{k}< 2a_{k-1}$ for all $k\geq3$, and (iv) $\gcd(a_i, a_{i+1},..., a_{i+3})=1$ for every subset $\{a_i,a_{i+1},...,a_{i+3}\}$. Therefore, according to the conjecture, every positive integer $x\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ greater than or equal to $16$ belongs to $C^{2}$ or is expressible as a sum of at most $4$ equal or distinct elements of $C^{2}$. This is equivalent to Lagrange's four square theorem.

My main doubts of the validity of this conjecture are related to exponential series, as it must be compatible with [Waring's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) numbers $g(k)$ and $G(K)$. In principle, I see no incompatibility.

My questions:

(i) can you offer some counterexample showing that the conjecture is false?

(ii) is the conjecture reasonable enough, at least heuristically?

(iii) can the restrictions be softened even more and have still a solid and reasonable generalization?

(iii) can you offer some advice on how could it be proved/disproved the conjecture to be true?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample. Let $a_n=2^n+1$, i.e. the sequence is [A000051](https://oeis.org/A000051)
$$
2, 3, 5, 9, 17, 33, 65, 129, 257, 513, 1025, 2049, 4097, 8193, 16385, \dots 
$$

It satisfies your properties for $N=1$. Indeed:

1. It's clearly strictly increasing
2. Both $2$ and $3$ belong to the sequence
3. $a_{k}< 2a_{k-1}$ is $2^k+1<2(2^{k-1}+1)$, which is equivalent to $1<2$
4. From $2(2^i+1)-(2^{i+1}+1)=1$ we see that $\gcd(2^i+1,2^{i+1}+1)=1$

So by your conjecture every integer $x\geq 3$ must be expressible as a sum of at most $3$ (possibly same) elements from this sequence. This is clearly impossible as each $a_n$ has at most two $1$s in its binary expansion, so sum of three such numbers can have at most six $1$s. So for example $x=(1111111)_2=127$ is not expressible as such sum.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Nice counterexample